# Is it possible to update a primary key column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I was asked to update a SQL Server table's primary key column, the column already has values. On inner joining with few other tables, I had to update the PK column values from another table. It's failing to do so due to duplicates, inserting value 435 to 2 or more PK column.

Any suggestion how it can be done?

```
UPDATE t
SET t.ID = c.NewID 
FROM Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table2 p ON p.ID = t.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 c ON c.ID = t.ID
WHERE c.status = 'Y'
```

Comment: Please post the query you are using, along with the table definitions.

Comment: Did u tried with Merge script ?

Comment: No, I have not used merge script. Does that work with pk column update?

Comment: It should , i assume there would be duplicates if u have used left join in the query, why would u need to use left join ?

Comment: If primary key constraint error occurs, try to find null values first or duplicates

Comment: Actually I'm trying to update the same value 435 to 2 or 3 rows of pkcolumn. That's the problem. But that is what the requirement is. UPdate the pk column with value 435 to more than one row.

Comment: Can u post the complete table column names please if you can, if u have more than one PK defined in the table you can update the first primary column

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your PK is called `A`, so:

- create a new column called `B`
- `update table set B = A`
- do the changes you need to `B`
- go through all the tables you have FK to your table; drop them, and make sure to reflect the data changes;
- drop the PK on `A`
- recreate it on `B`
- recreate all the FKs you dropped 3 steps ago on `B`

Simple :)

I'm joking, as you can see it is very complicated and error prone. You shouldn't have to worry about your PKs values - if you are there is something wrong in your design